# Rewrite the code from Angular/RXJS 4 to the 6

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm having great difficulty rewriting this code for angular 6. My angular application is giving frequent errors with the RXJS library. I have even tried to install Rxjs-compat, but so far, nothing has solved.

```
public publicar(): void {
    this.bd.publicar({
      email: this.email,
      titulo: this.formulario.value.titulo,
      imagem: this.imagem[0]
    })

    let acompanhamentoUpload = Observable.interval(1500)

    let continua = new Subject()

    continua.next(true)

    acompanhamentoUpload
      .takeUntil(continua)
      .subscribe(() => {
        //console.log(this.progresso.status)
        //console.log(this.progresso.estado)
        this.progressoPublicacao = 'andamento'

        this.porcentagemUpload = Math.round(( this.progresso.estado.bytesTransferred / this.progresso.estado.totalBytes ) * 100)

        if(this.progresso.status === 'concluido') {
          this.progressoPublicacao = 'concluido'
          //emitir um evento do componente parent (home)
          this.atualizarTimeLine.emit()
          continua.next(false)
        }
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with  `.takeUntil(continua)` You must change it to `.pipe(takeUntil(continua))` 
Also you must import it like:

```
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
```

Your code would be like:

```
public publicar(): void {
    this.bd.publicar({
      email: this.email,
      titulo: this.formulario.value.titulo,
      imagem: this.imagem[0]
    })

    let acompanhamentoUpload = Observable.interval(1500)

    let continua = new Subject()

    continua.next(true)

    acompanhamentoUpload
    .pipe(takeUntil(continua))
      .subscribe(() => {
        //console.log(this.progresso.status)
        //console.log(this.progresso.estado)
        this.progressoPublicacao = 'andamento'

        this.porcentagemUpload = Math.round(( this.progresso.estado.bytesTransferred / this.progresso.estado.totalBytes ) * 100)

        if(this.progresso.status === 'concluido') {
          this.progressoPublicacao = 'concluido'
          //emitir um evento do componente parent (home)
          this.atualizarTimeLine.emit()
          continua.next(false)
        }
      })
  }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for help me!